# D3.js blinking arc in chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events, chord-diagram

I have a chord diagram and on certain arc if I move my mouse from chord to chord (not arc-to-arc) I found that the all the chords are blinking. I don't move from an arc to another one I simply stay in the same one but it's blinking. If I compare [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/u04e6xgp/8/) to this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/eleyine/raw/6846156/) when I am on "Yemen" and I move my mouse from chord to chord (in Yemen) the other chords doesn't blink. But on my diagram Let's say arc "MB" and I move my mouse all the other chords are blinking.

```
  g.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", 6)
  .attr("dy", 15)
  .filter(function(d) { return d.value > 110; })
  .append("svg:textPath")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#group" + d.index + "-" + j; })
  .text(function(d) { 
    if (d.value<5000){return "";}
    return array[d.index].name; });
  }, remove_first_diagram());

  var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      //console.log('mouseIn');
    })
    .on("mouseout", 
      function (d) { 
        //console.log('mouseOut');
       });

  function mouseover(d, i) {
      chordPaths.classed("fade", function(p) {
        return p.source.index != i
            && p.target.index != i;
      });
    }
```

Comment: I have removed the mouseover and it works fine for me without any transitions & flicker

Comment: thanks! But I want to keep my mouseover effect. I'm trying to find out I think somehow my javascript have some conflicts within the  mouseover effect... I keep digging in :)

Comment: Hi Papouche, Did you try with transition() function? http://4waisenkinder.de/blog/2014/05/11/d3-dot-js-tween-in-detail/